# How can I select all records from one table and if their id is present in another then get data from table 2 also?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relational-database

I want to get an array of **all players** back and the ones that have been added to TeamSelections I would like to be able to get their data from that table also. How do I go about this?

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]   def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.belongs_to "club", index: true
      t.belongs_to "club_rl", index: true
      t.string "nickname"
      t.string "first_name"
      t.string "middle_names"
      t.string "last_name"
      t.date "dob"
      t.string "pob"
      t.string "position"
      t.integer "number"
      t.string "height"
      t.boolean "international", default: false
      t.string "national_team"
      t.timestamps
    end   end end

class CreateTeamSelections < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :team_selections do |t|
      t.belongs_to "season", index: true
      t.belongs_to "club", index: true
      t.belongs_to "player", index: true
      t.integer "fixture_week"
      t.integer "position", limit: 1
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I do not get your question.  You want players `but the ones that have been added to TeamSelections`.  So the players that are not linked to a team.  Ok.  but you want also `get their data from the TeamSelections table` ?  You just said you want users that are not associated to TeamSelections...?

Comment: Okay so... I want to bring back ALL PLAYERS. Then for the players that have a record in the TeamSelections table I would like to populate it's position integer in the HTML e.g. "<div data-position='6'">Tony Roberts</div>

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord` [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) should do this for you quite well. As you want to iterate over all `players` and put player position if he/she is in a `team_selection`.

(P.S - Assumed a player has_many :team_selections if its has_one then please use team_selection instead of team_selections)

```
Player.includes(:team_selections).each do |p|
  if p.team_selections.present?
    # insert their position in the HTML element
  end
end
```